# Looking for Elegant Way to Write this Code

Tags: python

I am looking for an elegant way to write this code. (Python 2.7)

The code below sits in a for loop. When the starting `status` of an `item` is say, `s2`, I need it to run iteratively until it reaches `status` `s7`.

If the success returns `False`, then it will stop and stay at that level, and the loop continues with the next `item`.

I'm hoping not to use `try:` to avoid the use of exceptions. The True / False `success` boolean should be sufficient for this purpose. Please correct me if you think I should consider otherwise.

Here's the code I have attempted. I am trying to find a more elegant solution.

```
def do_s1(): # similar for other status
  if condition:
    success = True
  else:
    success = False
  return success

for i in items:
  if status[i] = s1:
    success_s1 = do_s1()
    if success_s1:
      success_s2 = do_s2() 
      if success_s2:
        success_s3 = do_s3()
        # all the way until do_s7(), iteratively

  if status[i] = s2:
    do_s2()
    if success:
      do_s3() # all the way until do_s7(), iteratively
...

  if status[i] = s7:
    do_s7()
    # some code
```

The loop should iterate to the next item every time success turns False, or when it reaches s7

Comment: `def do_s1(): return condition`.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to change some of those `=` to `==`

Comment: ahh yes, it's actually ```==``` , mistakenly wrote them as ```=``` here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I don't recommend using list comprehensions or generators solely for the side effect of executing a function on each item of a list. Here, however, it has the potential to greatly reduce the size of your code.

Start by putting each of your `do_*` functions in a list, and each status in a separate list:

```
dos = [do_s1, do_s2, do_s3, do_s4, do_s5, do_s6, do_s7]
ss = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7]
```

Now, we'll take advantage of the `all` function, which consumes elements of a sequence until it finds one that is false

```
for i in items:
    for j, s in enumerate(ss):
        if status[i] == s:
            all(f() for f in dos[j:])
```

And that's it. `all` returns `True` if all the calls return `True`, but you aren't actually interested in the return value of `all`, just the fact that it stops evaluating functions as soon as one of them returns `False`.

You could, however, replace the call to `all` with an third explicit loop:

```
for f in dos[j:]:
   if not f():
       break
```

---

`all` works here because your nested `if` statement can be simplified from

```
  if status[i] == s1:
    success_s1 = do_s1()
    if success_s1:
      success_s2 = do_s2() 
      if success_s2:
        success_s3 = do_s3()
        # all the way until do_s7(), iteratively
```

to

```
if status[i] == s1:
    if do_s1() and do_s2() and ... do_s7():
```

with `and` short-circuiting the evaluation of the various `do_*` functions whenever one fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator in the do_s1 function:

```
return True if condition else False
```

The remaining code is a bit confusing since I don't know what type of variables *status* contains and what s1,s2 and s3 are.

Comment: or just `return bool(condition)`

Answer (score 0):

I second Giodo's recommendation to use the ternary operator.

You could try to end the `do_s1()` function with a call to the next one on a successful execution. Then you wouldn't have to do the hierarchical calls explicitly:

```
def do_s1(): # similar for other statuses
  success = True if condition else False
  if success:
    do_s2()

def do_s2():
  success = True if condition else False
  if success:
    do_s3()
```

...

```
if status[i] == s1:
  do_s1() # goes all the way up to s7
```

and if you get other statuses that start in between, the sequential execution still works:

```
if status[i] == s2:
  do_s2() # also goes until s7
```